# remove Anonymous user from "Entity Reference" users list

Tags: 7, entities

in my case a project has a technical team, so project content type has a user reference field which is created by Entity reference module. but in node creation form, an "Anonymous" user is available to select.

[image]

how can I remove it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way would be to create a View with an "entity reference" display to show all users with an id greater than zero, then use the Views "Entity selection mode" for your entity reference field:

[image]

You can choose the View you just created and the anonymous user will no longer show.

There's also the [Entity Reference View Widget](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference_view_widget) module which provides an advanced version of this functionality, though it's still in alpha.

Comment: Thanks for introducing entity reference views integration.